# Vector space of a square integrable function

Tags: vector-spaces

The space L^2 ([-π,π]) is the set of all square integrable functions defined on -π≤t≤π. In other words,
L^2 ([-π,π])={f:[-π,π]→R; ∫_(-π)^π▒〖|f(t)|^2 dt〗<∞}.
(1 point) Show that L^2 ([-π,π]) forms a vector space on R with the addition f+g and scalar multiplication αf for f,g ∈L^2 ([-π,π]),α∈R which is defined as follows.
a) (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x),
b) (αf)(x)=αf(x).

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 0):

A set of objects, together with a defined commutative addition and scalar product, is a vector space if it is closed under the operation (for any two objects, u, v, in the set and scalars, a, b, au+ bv is in the set, there exist a 0 vector (for any object, v, in the set, v+ 0= v) and every vector has a negative (for any object, v, in the set there exist an object, u, in the set so that u+ v= 0.

Here we are given the set of square integrable functions as the set, (f+ g)(x)= f(X)+ g(x) as the addition and (cf)(x)= cf(x) as scalar product.  It is easy to see that if 0(x)= 0 for all x then (f+ 0)x= f(x) and that 0(x) is square integrable and that if f is square integrable so is -f because $\int_{-\pi}^\pi (-f(x))^2dx=  \int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x) dx$.

Of course $\int_{-\pi}^\pi (af+ bg)^2 dx= a\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2+ 2ab\int_{-\pi}^\pi fg dx+ b^2\int_{-\pi}^\pi g^2 dx$ so the "hard part" is showing that if f and g are square integrable then fg is integrable.

Comment: I want the exact solution I already know that this question is hard that's why ı am asking to you. Thank you for your useful comment.

Comment: Please reply me.